# CF7 Flamingo get messages from specific form

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-flamingo-plugin

How can i get the messages from a certain form?

With this i can get all the inbound messages:

```
<?php
        
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'flamingo_inbound',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            
            echo '<article>';
            echo get_the_title();
            echo '</article>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

But i wanna show only the messages from a specific form for the current month. I search on Google and here but i can not find any example or anything for it so i hope somebody knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a solution, maybe not the nicest php writing but it works:

```
<?php
    $currentmonth = date('m');

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'flamingo_inbound',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'monthnum' => $currentmonth
    );


    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        echo '<ul>';
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            
            $results = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );

            foreach($results['_meta'] as $result) {
            
                $normaldata = unserialize($result);
                
                if ($normaldata['post_id'] == '1234') { // The id of the post where the form is send from
                    $title = get_the_title();
                    echo '<li>' . $title . '</li>';
                } else {
                  
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```